# Google Chrome resets font size after clicking link before navigating to the new page

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fonts

I'm using MacOS Sonoma, and Google Chrome Version 120.0.6099.129 (Official Build) (arm64)

This is the behaviour:

1. Enter a website (e.g. Google, Hacker News, or anything else with links)
2. Set larger font size using "command +" a few times
3. Click on a link (if you use a slower connection you can see it better)
4. Observe the font go back to 100% for the whole time it takes before the page changes to the new URL

[See video demo](https://imgur.com/d2hU7bP)

How to debug this?

Answer (score -1):

I believe this may be a feature instead of a bug of google chrome I believe the zoom settings set via (⌘+)or (⌘-) are not global and are instead stored on a per website/domain basis so once you navigate away from a domain chrome sets the text size to the to either the user selected zoom, if set, or the or the global zoom which by default is 100% of the domain being navigated to, but I do agree its a bit annoying to see the text resize I would think the page should clear before any of this resizing occurs.

Also I would add you can set a global zoom if you have a preferred zoom sizing you would like across all pages, if you go to the setting page of chrome (,⌘) search zoom at the top and that setting will set it so that any link you click will be set to that zoom level by default and you wont encounter that resizing reset across pages unless of course you change it on that site.

Comment: You miss the point: chrome is taking the whole extra effort of re-rendering the a  130% zoomed website a second time at 0% zoom level BEFORE rendering the next website. That's a lot of extra work.